# Android - How to Keep chrome active when locked

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, gps

I am working on my personal project to keep my kids safe and on-eye. I am currently working on web page, that will track my kids GPS location every minute. I know there are a lots of apps, but I want to create customized one just for me and my wife.

**My problem:**

When the kids phone (android) locks, it deactivates Google Chrome too. This way the JavaScript code is not working and not sending GPS data to my database server (MySql - MariaDB)

**My question is:**

Is there some method to keep awake the Google Chrome (or alternate browser) when the phone is locked? I Googled around a lot, but got no success.

Thanks for any suggestion.

For illustration, **here is part of my code:**

```
<script>

  function get_location() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map, errmap, {
          maximumAge: 6000,
          timeout: 2000,
          enableHighAccuracy: true
      });
  }

  function writetodb(position) {
      {
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else {
              // code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {}
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "./getposition.php?kid_id=<?php echo $kid_id;?>&lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
      }
  }


  function show_map(position) {
      writetodb(position);
  }

  function errmap() {
      console.log('.');
  }


  function startWorker() {
      if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
          if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
              w = new Worker("./js/worker.js");
          }
          w.onmessage = function(event) {
              get_location();
          };
      } else {
          console.log("Sorry! No Web Worker support.");
      }
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    startWorker();
  }
</script>
```

**worker.js:**

```
function sendbackmsg() {
  var i = 1;
  postMessage(i);
  setTimeout("sendbackmsg()",60000);
}

sendbackmsg();
```

PS: This browser tab is always open in kids phone (however usually minimized).
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Do you think making an android app will be good in this case instead of running javascript in a browser to track GPS location?

Comment: @Ali I dont want to upload my app / neither install .apk to kids phone. That's the reason i am not using "ready to use" apps, I simply do not trust them. Want to keep my data and (of course) my kids safe. I have 4 kids, they needs a database :)

Comment: I understand :) but what happens if they close the browser? It will stop working - it will be the same as if they uninstall the apk. You can run a background task in android, you can Keep it live in the notification (or hide it)

Comment: Kids are between 7 and 12 years. My web page design is simple. Just an <img> tag with our family picture, they told me they will never close it. they are opening new tab for browsing.

Comment: See: [Background Geolocation ServiceWorker - onMessage Event order when Web App regains focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44233409/295004) and especially the links in the question. Short answer - build a native (Java/Kotlin) app, web apps would need a new set of permissions and browser support.

Comment: It is your call :) but if I were you, i will go with a small android app instead

Comment: I have a similar need to build a start-to-run app, which I want to tell the user to run / walk after various periods of time from their pocket / arm pouch...